# C# - write stream of bytes to barcode instead of string

Tags: c#, .net, byte, barcode, zxing

I need to write some message into the aztec bar code which contains from encrypted data, compressed data and some characters. Since the encoding of encrypted and compressed data could be messed when encoding it to ascii, because barcode writter needs string as an input parameter.

My question is : how can I write plain byte array to bar code?

I am using Zxing for generating bar codes in C#.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: When sending/receiving data you must always be able to tell the end of each piece of data.  This is done one of 3 ways.  1) Ascii : Terminate with a known character 2) Ascii or Binary : add byte count to beginning of data 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length messages.  So you need to be able to split the data on the receiving side to separate the binary and the ascii data.  Also, never take binary data and encode/decode using Ascii encoding.  Always use UTF8.  Ascii encoding removes non printable characters.  UTF8 does not change data.  So you can use UTF8 with ascii sttring data.

Comment: @luka-kovac I think both the moderators and commenters missed your point, here - you're trying to figure out how to get ZXing to encode raw input binary rather than internally decoding what it assumes is Unicode text, right? I've got the same problem, and ZXing doesn't allow you to input a byte array rather than a string input. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use Base64 encoding. It's a way of encoding binary data of arbitrary length.